# TLSharp. Как получить только непрочитанные сообщения из чата, диалога или канала?

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

Задача - получить непрочитанные сообщения из определенного диалога/чата с помощью библиотеки TLSharp. Получаю сообщения с помощью следующего кода. Как определить, прочитано сообщение или нет? Или, как правильно составить запрос на получение сообщений, чтобы он выдавал только непрочитанные?

```
 TLRequestGetHistory request = new TLRequestGetHistory();
 var user1 = await getUser(client, user);
 request.Peer = new TLInputPeerChannel() { ChannelId = (user1 as TLChannel).Id, AccessHash = (user1 as TLChannel).AccessHash.Value };
 request.MaxId = -1;
 request.Limit = 10;
 var message = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLChannelMessages>(request);
 var res = message.Messages;
 List<Dictionary<string, object>> listMessages = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
 foreach (var mes in res)
 {
     if (mes is TLMessage)
     {
         TLMessage sms = mes as TLMessage;
         Dictionary<string, object> dictMessage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         dictMessage.Add("Text", sms.Message);
         listMessages.Add(dictMessage);
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getUnreadMentions

Comment: @aepot это через апи, а хотелось бы решение через библиотечку :( но все равно спасибо